# creating softlink to databases in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have few hundreds of databases generated by different tools and archived in a central area. All the files are stored in zipped format. I tried importing those databases into mysql server by creating soft links in the var directory, but i dont see any tables in mysql. I can see all the tables if i unzip the files.

Is there a way to link the zipped databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't directly have mysql read databases from Zip archives.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux then you can install the fuse-zip filesystem (and Fuse if it's not already installed).  This allows you to mount zip files as if they were filesystems.  Point MySQL to your mount path and it will recognize the contents of the zip file(s) like any other file on your system.

http://code.google.com/p/fuse-zip/

It should go without saying that there will be a performance penalty but considering these are archived databases I'm guessing that's not an issue.